# Play video only after its fully downloaded

Tags: actionscript-3, video, netstream

Flv seems like can't be use with loader but NetStream. But I wanted to play the video only after I have completely download it (smooth viewing with no buffering time). How can I do it with NetStream? And Can I have multiple video load at same time, and play it according to some array arrangement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check if `stream.bytesLoaded == stream.bytesTotal`